# How to install newer packages on Oracle Linux?

Tags: yum, arm, oracle-linux

On Oracle Linux, how to install newer packages?

For example, `yum install -y wireshark; wireshark --version` gives `Wireshark 2.6.2`,
but upstream is at `Wireshark 4.0.6`. I have `Last metadata expiration check: 2 days, 9:01:50 ago`.

```
> yum search -v wireshark
Loaded plugins: builddep, changelog, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache, groups-manager, needs-restarting, playground, repoclosure, repodiff, repograph, repomanage, reposync, system-upgrade, ulninfo
YUM version: 4.7.0
cachedir: /var/tmp/dnf-opc-3xezwdbs
========================================================================================= Name Exactly Matched: wireshark =========================================================================================
wireshark.aarch64 : Network traffic analyzer
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Provide    : wireshark = 1:2.6.2-15.el8

wireshark.src : Network traffic analyzer
Repo        : ol8_appstream
Matched from:
Other       : wireshark

======================================================================================== Name & Summary Matched: wireshark ========================================================================================
libvirt-wireshark.aarch64 : Wireshark dissector plugin for libvirt RPC transactions
Repo        : ol8_appstream
Matched from:
Provide    : libvirt-wireshark = 8.0.0-19.0.1.module+el8.8.0+21044+01700444

============================================================================================= Name Matched: wireshark =============================================================================================
wireshark-cli.aarch64 : Network traffic analyzer
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Provide    : wireshark-cli = 1:2.6.2-15.el8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Linux is a spin-off of Red Hat Enterprise and is an "enterprise" OS. That means *stability is king*. If you want something newer, you need a more cutting-edge distro *or* you need to point to a different repository.

For example, [EPEL](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/). However, that doesn't seem to have it either, so you can try to rebuild it [from the source RPMs that Fedora uses](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/x86_64/w/wireshark-4.0.6-1.fc39.x86_64.html), but you're likely to plunge into Dependency Hell if it requires new libraries or kernel calls.

Comment: On the [official website](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) in third party, it points to [`packages.fedoraproject.org`](https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/wireshark/wireshark/) and it says `v4.0.6` too. Is there no way to use that?

Comment: No, Fedora is the "cutting edge" version of RHEL. It will require libraries and other utilities much newer than RHEL/Oracle provide. That's why I said you need to rebuild the RPM from those sources, but linked to the libraries you already have.

Comment: See also: https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/linux/fedora-vs-red-hat-enterprise-linux